# Using addObjectsFromArray on a nil NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray, nsset

I have an array (arrayA) of type NSArray having custom objects in it and a NSMutableSet (setA) also having the custom objects of same class. I wish to merge the contents in both of these in a set to avoid duplicate values, so I used `[setA addObjectsFromArray:arrayA]` and then I print setA.

I have a scenario where in setA would be nil and arrayA would have some contents in it. My understanding was even if setA is nil, `[setA addObjectsFromArray:arrayA]` would add contents of arrayA in SetA, but when I print setA I get nil instead of objects in setA.

How does this "addObjectsFromArray" work exactly? or am I missing something here? Apple docs didn't give me much idea about the nil part of the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object is `nil` and you call a method on it, it will also return nil. Add a check of `setA` is nil, set it to a new `NSMutableSet`.

Remember, `[nil method]` always performs a noop. If you `id retVal = [nil methodThatReturnsObjParam]`, `retVal` will always be nil. If you `int iVal = [nil methodThatReturnsint]`, `iVal` will be 0. And so on.

Comment: Ohh my bad. Got it. I didn't think it that route. I was just thinking in terms of input and output. Thanks Leo!!!

Answer (score 0):

If setA is nil, then sending *any* message to setA has exactly *no* effect at all. There is no set, so you can't add things to it. You'll have to manually create an NSMutableSet* and add to it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple - check if `setA` is `nil` and if so, create the mutable set:

```
if (!setA) {
    setA = [NSMutableSet set];
}
[setA addObjectsFromArray:arrayA];
```

Calling any method on a `nil` pointer does nothing but return `nil`.